# How to get unique data for each column from the database in one query (Django ORM)?

Tags: django, orm, django-orm

I need to get UNIQUE data from EACH column
I have a list of fields:

```
MY_FIELDS = ['id', 'created', 'And_more_28']
```

My HORRIBLY INEFFECTIVE code that produces the correct result

```
qs = Sheets.objects.all()
v = []
v += [list(qs.values(v).distinct()) for v in MY_FIELDS]
```

I get what I need.... But at what cost? (28 requests is painful)
Tell me how to make one query out of this....

This is how it produces non-unique data for EACH column (tried it)

```
qs = Sheets.objects.all().values(*MY_FIELDS).distinct()
```

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: Postgress, if it impotantly....

I want use Django ORM.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second approach does produce unique values, but these are unique *combinations*. So if there are 10 fields with each 5 values, that already can result in at most *5<sup>10</sup>* results, so it scales *dramatically*.

But the good news is, we can solve this, by aggregating all columns into distinct lists. Indeed, with [**`ArrayAgg`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg):

```
MY_FIELDS = ['id', 'created', 'And_more_28']

from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg

qs = Sheets.objects.aggregate(
    **{'values_{f}': ArrayAgg('f', distinct=True) for f in MY_FIELDS}
)
v = [qs[f'values_{f}'] for f in MY_FIELDS]
```

This will produce lists of distinct values for each column, and all in *one* single query.

Comment: Super! It works! Big Thanks!